# Create product custom permalink in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

In Woocommerce Product page I have:
H1,
H2 (ACF field) and
SKU
Could I create generated automatically a product permalink with these 3 fields?

With this function I can display the product SKU, but I do not want the (#) in the url, just /SKUnumber:

```
function append_sku_string( $link, $post ) {

    $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID , '_sku', true );

    if ( 'product' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        $link = $link . '#' .$post_meta;

        return $link;
    }
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_sku_string', 1, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the **Permalink Manager Pro** plugin which is a perfect solution for my issue > https://permalinkmanager.pro/

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for contributing an answer. This is just a note to help you improve your answers. When using links, please quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Give credit to the author. Also, explain why your solution works.